# GNU Parallel does not do anything using remote execution

Tags: gnu-parallel, remote-execution

I just need a hint. I am trying to run the following command from the GNU parallel tutorial ([GNU Parallel tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html)):

```
parallel -S $SERVER1,$SERVER2 echo ::: running on more hosts
```

I replaced $SERVERX with known hosts in my network. If I execute the command I'm getting asked for my password for each server and after that nothing happens anymore. The curser blinks all day long and I do not get any error message.
I tried different servers with the same result.

The verbose mode shows:

> ssh $SERVER1 -- exec perl -e @GNU_Parallel\\=split/_/,\\"use_IPC::Open3\\;_use_MIME::Base64\\"\\;eval\\"@GNU_Parallel\\"\\;\\$SIG\{CHLD\}\\=\\"IGNORE\\"\\;my\\$zip\\=\(grep\{-x\\$_\}\\"/usr/local/bin/bzip2\\"\)\[0\]\\|\\|\\"bzip2\\"\\;open3\(\\$in,\\$out,\\"\>\\&STDERR\\",\\$zip,\\"-dc\\"\)\\;if\(my\\$perlpid\\=fork\)\{close\\$in\\;\\$eval\\=join\\"\\",\\<\\$out\>\\;close\\$out\\;\}else\{close\\$out\\;print\\$in\(decode_base64\(join\\"\\",@ARGV\)\)\\;close\\$in\\;exit\\;\}wait\\;eval\\$eval\\;
>   and Followed by random characters

Something similar appears four times. I guess for the four jobs I started. I'd be very happy for help.

Comment: I think you are expected to set up passwordless `ssh` logins to all the remotes so **GNU Parallel** can get into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you are expected to set up passwordless ssh logins to all the remotes so GNU Parallel can get into them. – Mark Setchell

This was the right suggestion. Setting up key authentication using `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` did the job! Thank you very much now it works. A short hint in the tutorial would have been great.

Comment: In `man parallel_tutorial` section Prerequisites it says: `For remote running: ssh login on 2 servers with no password in $SERVER1 and $SERVER2`. How would you prefer the hint?